# Do Mariner 4 hand rendered images still exist?

Tags: mars, imaging, flyby, museum-exhibits, mariner

At the [NASA web site](http://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/display.cfm?News_ID=49506) is a story about how the first images returned from Mariner 4 were rendered by hand.

[image: Hand rendered image from Mariner 4]

Do these images still exist, for example in a museum?

Comment: This image was recently used as a poster for the [JPL's "Discovery at Mars" lecture from the von Kármán series](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/events/lectures_archive.php?year=2015&month=7). I didn't yet watch it in full, but it's entirely possible that Blaine Baggett would have mentioned that during his lecture. The video of it should be available as a recording shortly [here](http://www.ustream.tv/nasajpl2/videos).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was displayed publicly yesterday! At a [Karman lecture](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/events/lectures_archive.php?year=2015&month=7) held by Mr. Blaine Baggett, Director, Office of Communication and Education, JPL. It might not be archived and available to download right now, but soon it will. And I'm sorry for being a spoiler, but it is in the last few minutes of his show. Even the crayons used to draw it are preserved.

(I might add that I have no idea how this looks like anything on Mars. Does anyone know what region this could be?)

EDIT addition: Was this really the best map of Mars 50 years ago? According to the [link](http://www.directedplay.com/first-tv-image-of-mars) TidalWave provided in the a comment below. With the old canali and everything. Some progress in space exploration has been made indeed. Methink I see triagonal structures on the early images from Pluto, but they might be like Lowell's imaginations.
[image]

Comment: Says here what the image is of http://www.directedplay.com/first-tv-image-of-mars

Comment: And this is why I make sure my daughter learns her color by numbers - what if she has to hand render a transmission from another world?

Comment: Those "canali" are actually the back of Lowell's (and other's) eye... http://scienceblogs.com/universe/2012/09/28/the-canals-of-mars/ I'm not sure why it stuck for so long, but with the advent of better telescopes and photographic capabilities I think these canali became extinct.

Comment: Just to let you know, his name is actually Ti**l**dalWave. Note the extra 'L' between the i and d. Don't ask me why he chose that name, but if this had been an @ notification, it would not notify him just like my first few times on this site :/

Comment: @LocalFluff this has the answer to "Does anyone know what region this could be?" https://phys.org/news/2015-07-mariner-mars-years.html  the Video mentioned in [Do you recognize these space artists who made this (possibly) first “paint-by-numbers” image of Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26525/12102) also has a bit about it about 2/3 of the way through when it talks about the data coming in.

Comment: @TildalWave Thank you for that link, it also answers this question! [Do you recognize these space artists who made this (possibly) first “paint-by-numbers” image of Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26525/do-you-recognize-these-space-artists-who-made-this-possibly-first-paint-by-nu/52109#52109)

Comment: I've got photocopies of images of Pluto by Hubble that are maybe twenty pixels across. I doubt Lowell could have done better with ground based telescopes. Or did you mean Mars where you wrote Pluto.