# Difference between distance from Mars (Rmag) and B-plane R coordinate

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, gmat

I am running some GMAT simulations on Mars 2020 trajectory to Mars, following the ephemerides published by JPL.
I create a target sequence and target the planet using the b-plane coordinates B and T. I noticed that when setting T=0 and B=24000km (or any other value, for that matter), the spacecraft ends up at a distance from the centre of Mars that is smaller than this value, about 4000km.

The GMAT help file doesn't go into detail about the B parameters but mentions that w x r effects of rotating systems might not be simulated in some implementations. I tried changing the martian coordinate system from MJ2000Eq to ICRF and the results are identical.
I don't understand how this difference is created or how to configure the goal commands so that I can target a specific distance from the centre reliably, using the B-plane?
Rmag can be used in place of B or T, but it doesn't convey the side of the planet in which the spacecraft will be inserted

Answer (score 3):

A good overview of what the B-plane is and how it's defined is available [from the FreeFlyer guide](https://ai-solutions.com/_freeflyeruniversityguide/the_b_plane.htm).

The "B" in B-plane is the [hyperbolic impact parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_trajectory#Parameters_describing_a_hyperbolic_trajectory), the semi-minor axis of the hyperbola that is the spacecraft's orbit. Importantly, as the equations from Wikipedia show, **the impact parameter alone is not enough to determine the periapsis of the orbit.** The other parameter required in the hyperbolic excess velocity, $v_{\infty}$, which is also the square root of the [characteristic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_energy), $C3$.

You can think of the impact parameter as "*the distance by which a body, if it continued on an unperturbed path, would miss the central body at its closest approach.*" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_trajectory#:%7E:text=the%20distance%20by%20which%20a%20body%2C%20if%20it%20continued%20on%20an%20unperturbed%20path%2C%20would%20miss%20the%20central%20body%20at%20its%20closest%20approach.))

Unperturbed meaning we ignore the planet's (Mars) gravity in the B-plane representation. Mars' gravity will pull the spacecraft closer and therefore **the close approach distance, $r_p$, is always less than the impact parameter, $b$, value**.

Wikipedia gives a neat equation relating $r_p$ and $b$:
$$r_p=\frac{\mu}{v_{\infty}^2} \cdot (\sqrt{1+(\frac{b \cdot v_{\infty}^2}{\mu})^2}-1)$$
Which could be rearranged for $b$:
$$b=\frac{\mu}{v_{\infty}^2} \cdot \sqrt{(1+\frac{r_p \cdot v_{\infty}^2}{\mu})^2-1}$$

---

In GMAT I started with a Mars relative state vector for Mars 2020 from [HORIZONS](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/) on February 1st:

```
            JDUT ,            Calendar Date (UT ),                      X,                      Y,                      Z,                     VX,                     VY,                     VZ,
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
$$SOE
2459246.500000000, A.D. 2021-Feb-01 00:00:00.0000, -3.270678971433882E+06, -1.333631118481763E+06,  1.800947903043214E+06,  2.089538719640068E+00,  8.723492698345683E-01, -1.146618806007647E+00,
$$EOE
**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

I'll assume you can create the necessary GMAT components (spacecraft, propagators, coordinate frames, etc.) and just give you the mission sequence code:

```
%----------------------------------------
%---------- Arrays, Variables, Strings
%----------------------------------------

Create Variable C3 mu rp B dV angle BT BR;
GMAT mu = 42828.37; % GM for Mars
GMAT rp = 3389.5; % Mars target periapsis (km)

%----------------------------------------
%---------- Mission Sequence
%----------------------------------------

BeginMissionSequence;

GMAT angle = DegToRad(0); % B-Plane theta angle (radians, input is degrees)

% Target TCM
Target 'Target Mars B-Plane' DC1 {SolveMode = Solve, ExitMode = DiscardAndContinue, ShowProgressWindow = true};
    % Vary TCM
   Vary 'Vary TCM.V' DC1(TCM.Element1 = 0, {Perturbation = 1e-2, Lower = -0.05, Upper = 0.05, MaxStep = .01, AdditiveScaleFactor = 0.0, MultiplicativeScaleFactor = 1.0});
   Vary 'Vary TCM.N' DC1(TCM.Element2 = 0, {Perturbation = 1e-2, Lower = -0.05, Upper = 0.05, MaxStep = .01, AdditiveScaleFactor = 0.0, MultiplicativeScaleFactor = 1.0});
   Vary 'Vary TCM.B' DC1(TCM.Element3 = 0, {Perturbation = 1e-2, Lower = -0.05, Upper = 0.05, MaxStep = .01, AdditiveScaleFactor = 0.0, MultiplicativeScaleFactor = 1.0});
   Maneuver 'TCM' TCM(M2020);
    
    % Propagate
    Propagate 'Prop to periapsis' MarsFull(M2020) {M2020.Mars.Periapsis, StopTolerance = 1e-05};

    % Script
    BeginScript
        GMAT C3 = M2020.Mars.IncomingC3Energy;
        GMAT B = mu/C3*sqrt((1+rp*C3/mu)^2-1);
        GMAT BT = B*cos(angle);
        GMAT BR = -B*sin(angle); % recall that R is positive "down"
        GMAT dV = sqrt(TCM.Element1^2+TCM.Element2^2+TCM.Element3^2)*1000; % TCM dV (m/s)
    EndScript;
    
    % Achieve Targets
   Achieve 'Achieve B.T' DC1(M2020.MarsMJ2000Ec.BdotT = BT, {Tolerance = 1});
   Achieve 'Achieve B.R' DC1(M2020.MarsMJ2000Ec.BdotR = BR, {Tolerance = 1});
EndTarget

Write dV { Style = Concise, LogFile = false, MessageWindow = true }
```

I moved from an explicit "B.T & B.R" targeting to a perhaps more intuitive "B & $\theta$" representation. Here are a few example output plots, left an angle of 0°, and right an angle of 135°:

[image: angle 0]
[image: angle 135]

Comment: slightly related: [What's the planetary exploration word for "impact parameter" (distance of closest approach if gravity were "turned off")?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30406/12102)